# Doob decomposition for discrete-time, local/generalized submartingales

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

The well-known Doob decomposition theorem states that for an integrable submartingale $(X_n)$ adapted to some filtration $\mathcal F_n$, there exist an integrable martingale $M_n$ and a predictable increasing process $A_n$ such that $\forall n, X_n = M_n + A_n$.

A generalized submartingale is a process $X_n$ such that $\forall n, E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)$ exists and $\forall n, x_n\leq E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)$.

In Shiryaev's *Probability*, it is proven that the definitions of generalized submartingales and local submartingales are equivalent.

> Does Doob's decomposition extend to generalized martingales ? I'm mostly interested in the case where $X_n$ is non-negative, but may have infinite expectation.

If you know the answer, please provide any reference or external source you see fit.